# Python Container requirements for Memcached on AWS using ElastiCache

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memcached

What are the `.config` and `requirements.txt` settings for ElasticCache on AWS Beanstalk?

I want to use AWS ElastiCache service as we are already using AWS and have AWS Beanstalk Django app up and running.

in my `requirements.txt` I do have this but I guess I need to add some dependencies for the `memcached` to work:

```
Django==1.6.4
MySQL-python==1.2.5
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
south==0.8.4
whoosh==2.5.7
django-haystack==2.1.0
pylibmc==1.3.0
```

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
    CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': 'djangocache.XYZ.amazonaws.com:11211',
    }
}
```

With some testing the `pylibmc==1.3.0` is causing the errors and I think somedepndencies are missing in the `requirements.txt` file.

Also, when I run this locally, I do get

```
error 31 from memcached_get(:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_): A TIMEOUT OCCURRED
```

My assumption is something to do with `Security Groups` on AWS. I did open the 11211 port to my local IP and the `EC2 Instances` IPs but still get the timeout error. Not sure if I can even connect locally to ElasticCache.

==============================

**Answer:**

The error was only related to my local machine as AWS does not support "remote" connection for ElastiCache out of the box and my connection was blocked by AWS security settings. There may be some workarounds to make that work but I did not research that.

Bottom line: Everything works OK while running on AWS.